# Golang: Can I cast to chan interface{}

Tags: interface, casting, go, publish-subscribe, channel

I am trying to write a general purpose wrapper for subscriptions, something like:

```
type Subscriber interface{
    Subscribe(addr string) chan interface{}
}
```

Suppose there is a library I want to use which has a subscribe method in it, but which uses a `chan library.Object`. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
func (s *mySubscriber) Subscribe(addr string) chan interface{}{
    ch := make(chan library.Object)
    library.Subscribe(addr, ch)
    return chan interface{}(ch)
}
```

Currently, I don't believe such a cast is possible. And I don't want to modify the underlying library, since the wrapper should be agnostic to library implementations.

I've seen [Is there a way to cast Structs for sending over a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425490/is-there-a-way-to-cast-structs-for-sending-over-a-channel), but in that case the application can be modified to suit the need. Here, it can't. Is this possible? Is there a better way?

One solution is to pass in a general purpose channel into Subscribe, and to wait indefinetely on `chan library.Object` and fire anything that comes through on my general channel, but I didn't particularly like having to introduce another channel just to get around the type cast.

Comment: Go has no concept of "cast". Go hase type conversions, type assertions and interfaces (and type switches) and that's it. Type conversions come closest to cast in e.g. C. Talking about casts and cast not working will just blur your view of the problem which must be tackled by use of type conversions (won't work in your situation!), clever use of interfaces and appropriate type assertions/switches maybe combined with reflection.  Most "general purpose" stuff in Go is doomed to fail or become slow by kneedeep wading in reflection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't do this with just a cast. You have to use an extra channel, as you have already considered. Fortunately, there is a helper library for this already (disclaimer: I wrote it). You want the `Wrap` function.

- Documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/eapache/channels#Wrap
- Code: https://github.com/eapache/channels/

Comment: figures. shame. maybe in the future the authors will extend the type switching to support this. with arrays and maps we have the same issue, but at least there you can loop through the elements and type switch to interface{} one by one. There should be some way to do it with a channel, but maybe there's a good reason not?

Comment: The reason not is that the types have fundamentally different underlying memory layouts, so it's not as simple as a "cast" would be in C. For example, a []struct{x,y int} looks entirely different from a []interface{} so you can't just "pretend" it is one, you have to do the manual conversion. Unlike simple casts, the conversion can be expensive (as you say, you have to loop through each element), so they decided not to hide it since it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that stumbles on this issue and wants some inline code:

```
// wrap a timeout channel in a generic interface channel
func makeDefaultTimeoutChan() <-chan interface{} {
  channel := make(chan interface{})
  go func() {
    <-time.After(30 * time.Second)
    channel <- struct{}{}
  }()
  return channel
}

// usage
func main() {
  resultChannel := doOtherThingReturningAsync()
  cancel := makeDefaultTimeoutChan()
  select {
    case <-cancel:
      fmt.Println("cancelled!")
    case results := <-resultChannel:
      fmt.Printf("got result: %#v\n", results)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with Go generics:

```
func Wrap[T any](from chan T) chan any {
  to := make(chan any)
  go func() {
    var val T
    for {
      val = <-from
      to <- val
    }
  }()
  return to
}

func Unwrap[T any](from chan any) chan T {
  to := make(chan T)
  go func() {
    var val any
    for {
        val = <-from
        to <- val.(T)
    }
  }()
  return to
}
```