# How to define a single byte variable in go lang

Tags: variables, go, byte

I am a newbie to golang and want to find a way to define a **single** `byte` variable.

It's a demo program in *Effective Go* reference.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

func unhex(c byte) byte{
    switch {
    case '0' <= c && c <= '9':
        return c - '0'
    case 'a' <= c && c <= 'f':
        return c - 'a' + 10
    case 'A' <= c && c <= 'F':
        return c - 'A' + 10
    }
    return 0
}

func main(){
    // It works fine here, as I wrap things with array.
    c := []byte{'A'}
    fmt.Println(unhex(c[0]))

    //c := byte{'A'}    **Error** invalid type for composite literal: byte
    //fmt.Println(unhex(c))
}
```

As you see I can wrap a byte with array, things goes fine, but How can I define a single byte without using array? thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, this would work, using the [conversion syntax `T(x)`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
c := byte('A')
```

> Conversions are expressions of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and `x` is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.

See [this playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/c3xT_Ufuan).

```
cb := byte('A')
fmt.Println(unhex(cb))
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: @armnotstrong I have edited the answer to explain *why* it works.

Comment: It's like a cast in C or java,  but instead of write as `(byte) 'A'` it write as `byte('A')`, Am I understand that right?

Comment: Some people will get mad at you for comparing it to a cast, but yes, they're similar in function.

Comment: @armnotstrong sort of: the spec never mentions "casting", only "conversion": see this comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593367/golang-can-i-cast-to-chan-interface#comment39977784_25593367): "Go has **type conversions**, **type assertions** and **interfaces** (and **type switches**) and that's it. Type conversions come closest to cast in e.g. C."

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the `:=` syntax, you can still use a `var` statement, which lets you explicitly specify the type.  e.g:

```
var c byte = 'A'
```