# Difference between "variable declaration" and "short variable declaration" at local scope in Go

Tags: go, variable-assignment, declaration

According to this question [how-to-define-a-single-byte-variable-in-go-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775590/how-to-define-a-single-byte-variable-in-go-lang)

At a local scope:

```
var c byte = 'A'
```

and

```
c := byte('A')
```

My questions are:

1. Do they have the same mechanism?
2. Which one is more easy to understand by a go compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same type (`byte` is an alias for `uint8`) and value. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var c byte = 'A'
    d := byte('A')
    fmt.Printf("c: %[1]T %[1]v d: %[2]T %[2]v c==d: %v", c, d, c == d)
}
```

Output:

```
c: uint8 65 d: uint8 65 c==d: true
```

They are equally efficient; the runtime code is the same. They are both easy to understand by Go compilers.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).
>
> A short variable declaration uses the syntax:
>
> ```
> ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
> ```
>
> It is shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer
>   expressions but no types:
>
> ```
> "var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .
> ```

The "best" is a matter of style. Which reads better in a given context?

> [The Go Programming Language](http://www.gopl.io/)
>
> Alan A. A. Donovan · Brian W.Kernighan
>
> Because of their brevity and flexibility, short variable
>   declarations are used to declare and initialize the majority of local
>   variables. A var declaration tends to be reserved for local variables
>   that need an explicit type that differs from that of the initializer
>   expression, or for when the variable will be assigned a value later
>   and its initial value is unimportant.

Comment: The crucial point is that which one is better? in term of efficiency. If they are the same that means different people will use different ways to archive this. That might be a pretty sad for go's code convention.